# Using SMOTE to oversample a binary class; why is it returning random float values between 0 and 1?

Tags: python, imblearn, smote

I'm using SMOTE to resample a binary class `TARGET_FRAUD` which includes values 0 and 1. 0 has around 900 records, while 1 only has about 100 records. I want to oversample class 1 to around 800.

This is to perform some classificatioin modeling.

```
#fix imbalanced data
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

#bar plot of target_fraud distribution
sns.countplot('TARGET_FRAUD', data=df)
plt.title('Before Resampling')
plt.show()

#Synthetic Minority Over-Sampling Technique
sm = SMOTE()

# Fit the model to generate the data.
oversampled_trainX, oversampled_trainY = sm.fit_resample(df.drop('TARGET_FRAUD', axis=1), df['TARGET_FRAUD'])
resampled_df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(oversampled_trainY), pd.DataFrame(oversampled_trainX)], axis=1)
resampled_df.columns = df.columns

sns.countplot('TARGET_FRAUD', data=resampled_df)
plt.title('After Resampling')
plt.show()
```

This is the count of values before resampling:

```
TARGET_FRAUD:
0    898
1    102
```

This is the count of values after resampling:

```
1.000000    1251
0.000000     439
0.188377       1
0.228350       1
0.577813       1
0.989742       1
0.316744       1
0.791926       1
0.970161       1
0.757886       1
0.089506       1
0.567179       1
0.331502       1
0.563530       1
0.882599       1
0.918105       1
0.613229       1
0.239910       1
0.487373       1
...
```

Why is it producing random float values between 0 and 1? I only want it to return int values of 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have your dataset but based on your code I made a reproducible example. I cannot replicate what you are writing.

```py
from collections import Counter

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, y = make_classification(random_state=0, weights=[0.9, 0.1])
df = pd.DataFrame(X)
df["TARGET_FRAUD"] = y

print("Before resampling")
print(Counter(df["TARGET_FRAUD"]))


sm = SMOTE()

# Fit the model to generate the data.
oversampled_trainX, oversampled_trainY = sm.fit_resample(
    df.drop("TARGET_FRAUD", axis=1), df["TARGET_FRAUD"]
)
resampled_df = pd.concat(
    [pd.DataFrame(oversampled_trainY), pd.DataFrame(oversampled_trainX)],
    axis=1,
)

print("Before resampling")
print(Counter(resampled_df["TARGET_FRAUD"]))
```

which prints

```
Before resampling
Counter({0: 90, 1: 10})
Before resampling
Counter({0: 90, 1: 90})
```